# How to add multiple custom fees on cart order summary magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to add multiple custom fees on cart order summary magento2

[image]

Comment: You can use this budget-friendly extension for multiple extra fees: https://marketplace.magento.com/prince-magento2-extrafeepro.html

Answer (score 3):

ive been using this module myself:
https://amasty.com/extra-fee-for-magento-2.html

Here is a more budget option:
https://marketplace.magento.com/prince-magento2-extrafee.html

Or do you want to code it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to add custom fee on your order:

https://magecomp.com/magento-2-extra-fee.html

https://magecomp.com/magento-2-surcharge.html